# Cannot access form elements produced by java script using PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have used javascript to dynamically produce form fields in the form i used using addInput() function in javascript... but after i trigger javascript code and submit the form PHP code cannot access form field elements....

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="test.php" method="post">
University Name: <input type="text" name="college">
No. of branches:
<div id="dynamicInput">
          <select name="branches" id="branches" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex) addInput('dynamicInput');;" ">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
</select>
     </div>   
<script>
    var counter = 0;
var limit = 3;  
function addInput(divName)
{    var counter = 0;   
    var k=parseInt(document.getElementById("branches").value);
    var newdiv;
       while(k>0) 
           {
        newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + counter + " <br><input type='text' name='branch["+counter+"]'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
          k--;
           }




}
    </script>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

and the php code lets assume like this:

```
<?php
$name=$_POST["college"];
$text=$_POST["branch[0]"];
echo $name." ".$text"
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to var_dump($_POST); are you seeing anything?

Comment: no i dint try.. can u explain about it...

Comment: in your test.php do a var_dump($_POST); and let us see the result

Comment: can u write full code? :P

Comment: <?php var_dump($_POST);
$name=$_POST["college"];
$text=$_POST["branch[0]"];
echo $name." ".$text"
?>

Comment: thank you itz working... :D

Comment: Are you seeing branch array now in the $_POST?

Comment: itz working awesome :D but what is this var_dump ... can y explain if u are free... :)

Comment: i should not display dat branch array... is der anymethod to stop displaying that...?

Comment: var_dump will print the variable contents, everything.